# PHP variables in/out a function

Tags: php

I want to write data in a csv.

For that I call a function to fill it.
I don't know how to call the variable outside the function (without global) so i open the file in it, but i need to close it outside, and i can't have my $fileOpen variable:

```
function doMyCode($args)
{
   if (!isset($firstLoop)){
     $fileOpen = fopen('customers.csv', 'w');
     $firstLoop = true;
   }
[...]
     fputcsv($fileOpen, $rowData, ";");
}
fclose($fileOpen);
```

So, how can i do that? With good manners, i don't want to put one looper's counter (like `$i`)

UPDATE

The call to the function is in Magento, it's like the `array_map()`, but in this form i don't know how to send another parameter or return anything:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk(
    $theList->getSelect()->limit(10),
    array('exportClient')
);
```

This is the reason I have this doubt

Comment: You can add the variables as a parameter to the function

Comment: you can pass the file handle in, and open/close it outside `function doMyCode($args, $fileOpen){ ... }`

Comment: This is a bit too abstract… You do know that you can `return` values from functions…? Why do you need to close the file outside?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php may be this will help you

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to handle the file opening and closeing outside

```
function doMyCode($args, $fileOpen ){
  fputcsv($fileOpen, $args, ";");
}

$fileOpen = fopen('customers.csv', 'w');

foreach( $lines as $line ){
  doMyCode($line , $fileOpen );
}

fclose($fileOpen);
```

I would not open the file inside the function and close it elsewhere,  either open / close it inside that function or open / close it outside, otherwise it just gets too messy, is it open? is it closed? who knows....